# Removing points outside of standard distance circle in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, proximity

I have a feature class of companies where each may have multiple locations (for example, company A may have a cluster of points associated with it). For each company, I used the Standard Distance tool to create a feature class of circles, which surrounds the group of points for that company that is within 1 standard distance of the mean point. See the image below:

[image]

I highlighted the points that belong to a company and the standard distance circle for those group of points (the big green circle) for that company.

What I need to do is to remove all the points that fall outside a company's standard distance circle. So in the image, I need to remove the lone highlighted point in the top right corner among the cluster of red points. I need to do this for every company in the dataset (around 33,000 of them).

Here is what I have tried:

1. Use the Select Layer by Attribute tool two times to select company A, for example, in

   - the point feature class containing the points belonging to company A
   - the standard distance circle for company A
2. Use the Clip tool to keep the points for company A that fall inside company A's standard distance circle
3. Do 1 and 2 for every company in the dataset

I can write a Python script to execute this, but given that there are 33,000 companies, my sense is that this will be slow. Any suggestions for a more direct approach?

Comment: I suspect that this is easily achievable using Clip/Erase (if you want to permanently remove) or Intersect (if you just want to then select them).  In any event can you provide more details about what you have tried and perhaps replace your current picture with a blow up of just the top right bit that you describe in your question.  If you need an ArcPy solution then we'll need you to include a code snippet.  My recommendation is to see how far you can get with just the tool dialogs first.

Comment: @PolyGeo: Thanks! I've thought about ways to do this, but I just wanted to be sure first that there wasn't some obvious tool that I missed that accomplishes this task in one shot. Regarding the picture, the current picture includes all the relevant points in the question (all the dots highlighted belong to the same company, including the one in the top right corner).

Comment: Basic intersect will do. Remove points where point_company<>circle_company.